# One Select Statement returns uint whereas another returns Int64 on the same column?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using a MySql database and somewhere in my code I do a select like this:

```
using (MySqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID = @id";
        cmd.Transaction = transaction;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        cmd.Prepare();
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                result = new User()
                {
                    Id = reader.GetFieldValue<uint>(0),
                    NameFirst = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(1),
                    NameLast = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(2),
                    DateOfBirth = reader.GetFieldValue<DateTime>(3)
                };
            }
            else
            {
                result.NameFirst = ErrorCodeUtility.GetEnumName(ErrorCodes.SQL_INVALID_ID);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `Id = reader.GetFieldValue<uint>(0)` line is interesting because it works. The type is an unsigned integer so this is correct. But somewhere else in my code I do the follwing:

```
using (MySqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 1 ID FROM USERS WHERE ID = @id";
        cmd.Transaction = transaction;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        cmd.Prepare();
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                uint receivedId = reader.GetFieldValue<uint>(0);
                if (receivedId == id)
                {
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line `uint receivedId = reader.GetFieldValue<uint>(0);` fails. It tells me that the type is Int64 rather than the expected uint.

What could possibly have gone wrong here? I'm querying the exact same table and just limiting it to one column rather than all data as I am not interested in all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is that I used the MySql syntax wrong. Instead of writing

```
SELECT 1...
```

The Correct syntax is:

```
SELECT params FROM table WHERE conditions LIMIT number
```

So in this case at the end it would be:

```
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is in your Select Statement.

What you meant probably was :

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM USERS WHERE ID = @id
```

You missed Keyword 'TOP', because of which, you are getting the following output, which when returned is Int64.

[image]

Let me know, if it helps.

Comment: Turns out in MySQL the way to write it is `SELECT param FROM table WHERE condition...LIMIT number`. So to get just the first would be `LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

Just what I wanted to ask you, are you sure your sql statement is correct? What do you want to achieve with select 1...?

One more thing, I would recommend to not use * when using select queries. Use explicit columns you need for certain query.